# SonarQube Quality Gate is not working in Incremental analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, bamboo, incremental-build

Sonarqube is integrated with bamboo and we are using bitbucket as SCM.

Am I right that quality gate set is not working when we are performing incremental analysis?

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]. what is your question and desired result

Comment: What is incremental analysis?

Comment: preview/incremental mode @janos

Comment: And what do you mean by "quality gate is not working" ?

Comment: this issue was resolved by upgrading the sonarqube version. thanks :)